# Display progress bar while data is loading

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to display a progress bar while data is loading and once data is loaded I want to hide the progress bar.

For the **testing purpose**, I have just added 10 seconds and it works.

```
private async Task ProgressBarAsync()
{
    _isProgressVisible = true;
   RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsProgressVisible);

   await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    isProgressVisible = false;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsProgressVisible);
}
```

However, in the following **actual code**, does not show progress bar.

```
private async Task RefreshStudentList()
{
   //display progressbar
   _isProgressVisible = true;
   RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsProgressVisible);

   // load data
   var task =  _studentService.GetStudentAsync();
   await task;
   Students = new ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel>(task.Result.ConvertAll(x => new ClassViewModel(x)));

   //hide progressbar
   _isProgressVisible = false;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsProgressVisible);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've bind IsProgressVisible properly?

Comment: See my updated question

Comment: Are you sure you call the RefreshStudentList method from the UI Thread?  You should try to encapsulate your "RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsProgressVisible);" call with a InvokeOnMainThread(() => ...);

Comment: could you please illustrate your idea in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using InvokeOnMainThread:

```
private async Task RefreshStudentList()
{
   //display progressbar
   _isProgressVisible = true;
   InvokeOnMainThread(() => RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsProgressVisible));

   // load data
   var data =  await _studentService.GetStudentAsync();
   Students = new ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel>
       (data.ConvertAll(x => new ClassViewModel(x)));

   //hide progressbar
   _isProgressVisible = false;
   InvokeOnMainThread(() => RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsProgressVisible));
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I have just tried and it does not work.

Comment: is it possible to create a github sample project with your code?